# How to generate a macOS Cocoa Date/Time in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, datetime, cocoa

Basically I am trying to figure out a way to convert the current date/time into a MacOS Cocoa Date, for example one like this "557799045" (can be up to 18 digits). I am able to convert a Cocoa timestamp into a normal date like so.

```
unix = datetime(1970, 1, 1)  # UTC
cocoa = datetime(2001, 1, 1)  # UTC
delta = cocoa - unix  # timedelta instance 
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(int("557799045")) + delta 
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

So now I am looking to do the opposite by again converting the current date into this "Cocoa" Timestamp. This application will only be on macOS so it's alright if it is OS dependent.

Comment: It’s just a count of seconds using a different epoch. It’s January 1, 2000 or 2001, I can’t remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cocoa` to substract from `utcnow()` and get `total_seconds()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
from datetime import datetime
cocoa = datetime(2001, 1, 1)
adjusted_time = datetime.utcnow() - cocoa
adjusted_time.total_seconds()

Out[]:
557802606.825758
```

If you need it as an `int` just use `int(adjusted_time.total_seconds())`

Just to confirm you can use `tz` aware `datetime`s, e.g.:

```
In []:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
cocoa = datetime(2001, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
adjusted_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - cocoa
adjusted_time.total_seconds()

Out[]:
557802607.343162
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the same in java?